# Ruby Gem for social profiles integration into native rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am building a rails website where user needs to add his social platform information such as Facebook, Github , LinkedIn and Twitter profile links. To make sure that the profile of the person same as he claims I am looking a method to verify it.

Is there any gem which authenticates the profile and then only after confirmation retrieves that data to that respective user table in the database? 
Do I need to build this plugin from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Well Its fairly easy to implement with `Onmiauth` but there is even one [social-login-in-rails plugin](https://github.com/mohitjain/social-login-in-rails) available. It very easy to implement and have [demo app](http://social-login-in-rails.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in) as well.